# What are all the standard CGI environment variables?

Tags: cgi, environment-variables

CGI scripts should have access to a list of environment variables set by the web server. What are their names?

Comment: I'm asking because most of the links to CGI specifications from http://www.w3.org/CGI/ are down.

Comment: It seems the specification hasn't been updated in 15 years and all the entities that were involved in it don't even exist anymore. I mean, NCSA??? Really??? They haven't been involved in the web ever since the Mosaic team left NCSA to found Netscape and Spyglass. Oh, and while we're on the topic: Netscape??? Spyglass???

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See [RFC 3875](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3875) for the CGI spec, which has all the info you need. :-)

From the RFC:

```
  meta-variable-name = "AUTH_TYPE" | "CONTENT_LENGTH" |
                       "CONTENT_TYPE" | "GATEWAY_INTERFACE" |
                       "PATH_INFO" | "PATH_TRANSLATED" |
                       "QUERY_STRING" | "REMOTE_ADDR" |
                       "REMOTE_HOST" | "REMOTE_IDENT" |
                       "REMOTE_USER" | "REQUEST_METHOD" |
                       "SCRIPT_NAME" | "SERVER_NAME" |
                       "SERVER_PORT" | "SERVER_PROTOCOL" |
                       "SERVER_SOFTWARE" | scheme |
                       protocol-var-name | extension-var-name
  protocol-var-name  = ( protocol | scheme ) "_" var-name
  scheme             = alpha *( alpha | digit | "+" | "-" | "." )
  var-name           = token
  extension-var-name = token
```

Answer (score 2):

http://www.cgi101.com/book/ch3/text.html

Answer (score 2):

The "hoohoo" machine at NCSA that has the CGI documentation is down, but [here's what seems to be a mirror](http://web.bilkent.edu.tr/WWW/hoohoo/cgi/env.html).

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google [search](http://www.cgi101.com/book/ch3/text.html) finds the what you need.